# How to remove a particular elements from an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have array with values: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
How to remove values, for example with particular elements: [2,3,4,5]
In result, i need get: [1,6,7,8,9]
How to remove one element from array, i know

```
function remove(array, value) {
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] == value) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But, I need to remove not one element from array. I need to remove multiple elements. Please, help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Is there some particular reason you need to modify the array *in place*? Just call `.filter` and return a new array.