# Remove multiple elements from array by value in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

When I want to remove one element, it is easy. This is my function:

```
function removeValues(array, value) {
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] == value) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

But how do I remove multiple elements?

Comment: What multiple elements? Please explain with an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a particular elements from an array in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595155/how-to-remove-a-particular-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Call `removeValues` for each value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript arrays: remove all elements contained in another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957348/javascript-arrays-remove-all-elements-contained-in-another-array)

Answer (score 16):

Here a simple version using ES7:

```
// removing values
let items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let valuesToRemove = [1, 3, 4]
items = items.filter((i) => !valuesToRemove.includes(i))
```

For a simple version for ES6

```
// removing values
let items =[1, 2, 3, 4];
let valuesToRemove = [1, 3, 4]
items = items.filter((i) => (valuesToRemove.indexOf(i) === -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

[1, 4, 3].reverse().forEach((index) => {
    items.splice(index, 1)
})

// [0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Answer (score -2):

I believe you will find the kind of functionality you are looking for in Javascript's built in array functions... particularily [Array.map();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.filter();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
//Array Filter
function isBigEnough(value) {
  return value >= 10;
}
var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough);
// filtered is [12, 130, 44]


//Array Map (Can also be used to filter)
var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
var doubles = numbers.map(function(num) {
  return num * 2;
});
// doubles is now [2, 8, 18]. numbers is still [1, 4, 9]

/////UPDATE REFLECTING REMOVAL OF VALUES USING ARRAY MAP

var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
a.map(function(v,i){
  if(v%2==0){
 a.pop(i);
  }
});
console.log(a);

// as shown above all array functions can be used within the call back to filter the original array. Alternativelty another array could be populated within the function and then aassigned to the variable a effectivley reducing the array.
```

Comment: What exactly has `.map` to do with this?

Comment: give an example so the OP can see what you mean.

Comment: [QUOTE] Summary
The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

Comment: Right. So how would you use it to remove an element?

Comment: I usually use map on multidimensional arrays when I need to get odd data out. I simply push the values to a new array that I return. It might not be the best way but its not the worst either.

Comment: @kurt i upvoted your answer at first, but after you updated the answer with an example i am forced to downvote it as it does not answer op's and felix's question. op needs to remove elements from an array, not alter their value.

Comment: *"I simply push the values to a new array that I return."* So you are not actually removing elements from the array you call `.map` on. This could be a good answer if you didn't try to include `.map`.

Comment: I see you point. Technically im returning a modified clone. But you can still use it to remove values from the array. see my example http://jsfiddle.net/pnL0awcv/

Comment: @Banana I have updated the code example further to show that Array.map(); can be used to modify the array it was called on.

Comment: @FelixKling please see updated example removing values from an array using Array.map

Comment: That's not the correct use of `.map`. If you are not actually returning anything from the callback to create a new array, i.e. you just want to iterate over the array, use [**`.forEach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Again, using `.filter` is great. `.map` has no place here.

Comment: `pop` does not take an argument.